# Как можно понять, какие php extensions использует код?

Tags: php

Всем привет!
На меня свалилось изучения большого php проекта, для унификации архитектуры, на которой он крутится. А раньше я с php дела не имел.

И появился вопрос, можно ли как-то по коду понять, какие extensions ему требуются?

Comment: Кроме прямого анализа кода - боюсь, никак. Если в проекте есть регрессионное тестирование, то можно гонять тесты на сыром PHP, постепенно добивая его расширениями.

Comment: Если есть composer.json, то в нем в зависимостях монут быть указаны все расширения.

Answer (score 2):

Можно развернуть копию проекта на тестовой площадке, имеющей только расширения по-умолчанию. Повысить детализацию логов и посмотреть на ошибки в логах. Путем добавления расширений добиваетесь нормальной работы и получаете список необходимых расширений (которые следует сразу задокументировать)

Answer (score -1):

Зачастую наименование расширения и наименование функций, входящий в него имеют что-то общее. Например, расширение php_mysql определяет большой набор функций mysql_xxxx().

Второй вариант - читать документацию каждого используемого расширения и анализировать код (поиск по тексту) на вхождение каких-то идентификаторов (функций, констант)...